# what is the purpose of using an uuid (or random unique number) instead of index

Tags: database, indexing, uuid

why did i see so many repo with uuid token instead of index ? whereas if the token is an index we could find the instance directly instead of go trough all the instance and check if the tokens match.

(I realized this by looking at the repo of nuscene)

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "index"? A simple integer ID, or something different...

Comment: @TheImpaler I mean a simple integer ID that is equal to the place of an object in an array.